# Setup.py install. Package init file 'graph\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)

Tags: python, setup.py

My directory's structure:

```
Projects/
|- VirtualEnv/
|- Graph/
   |- graph/
   |  |- __init__.py
   |  |- create_structure.py
   |- setup.py
   |- MANIFEST.in
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import graph

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name='MyGraph',
        version='1.0',
        packages = find_packages("graph"),
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts':
                ['start_graph = graph.create_structure:go']
            },
        install_requires = [
            "pandas>=0.25.1",
            "teradatasql>=16.20.0.50"
        ],
        include_package_data=True
    )
```

I created virtualenv

```
virtualenv VirtualEnv/env
```

Then I install package by

```
VirtualEnv/env/Scripts/python Graph/setup.py install
```

After this I activated virtualenv

```
source VirtualEnv/env/Scripts/activate
```

And run "start_graph" (command from setup.py) and got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Developers\kdnikish\Projects\VirtualEnv\env\Scripts\start_graph-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('MyGraph==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'start_graph')()
  File "D:\Developers\kdnikish\Projects\VirtualEnv\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "D:\Developers\kdnikish\Projects\VirtualEnv\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "D:\Developers\kdnikish\Projects\VirtualEnv\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "D:\Developers\kdnikish\Projects\VirtualEnv\env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graph'
```

Why it is not working? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you do the `install` before the `activate`?

Comment: Yes, I did. First: create virtualenv. Second: install. Third: activate virtualenv

Comment: Then the project is installed outside of the virtual environment.

Comment: I see. Maybe it's an old version, that doesn't have a `graph` module, since `packages` was faulty. Did you try doing the install again from within the virtual environment?

Comment: I created tar.gz by `python setup.py sdist` then I installed this archive by `VirtualEnv/env/Scripts/pip install Graph/dist/MyGraph-1.0.tar.gz`. After this I could get  result by "start_graph" command.

Comment: I tried to reinstall it from within the virtual environment, but still the same. So now I can install my package only from archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the culprit might be the `packages` parameter. It probably should be `packages=find_packages()` or more explicitly: `packages=find_packages(src='.')`. See the [*setuptools* documentation on "Using find_packages()"](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages).

Also it is probably better to be in the same directory as the setup script when executing it:

```
cd Graph
../VirtualEnv/env/Scripts/python setup.py install
```

You can also remove the `import graph` instruction from your `setup.py`, I don't see any need for it, and anyway it usually breaks sooner or later.

Then for debugging, locate the `MyGraph.egg-info` directory and look inside the `top_level.txt` and `SOURCES.txt` files. These should help you figure out if the packaging has been done right.

Comment: I don't lnow how, but now it is working. I did nothing espicial. Just repeated all actions again and run install command from  the same directory as the setup script. Whatever, thank you for your help!